# Avoiding Multiple Location Services Alerts

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiwebview, location

Let's say I have an a native iOS application that's presenting two or more webviews that request permission for location services.

For example, imagine an application that compares the map results for a given query - eg, user submits an address, one webview shows the results from google maps, another from bing, etc.

Is there any way to avoid each of the discrete web views requesting, by way of a disruptive alert view, permission for location services?

If the sole purpose of the app is to compare various location-based assets, it would seem that my application should ask the user *once* if they approve of the application using location services. How can my webviews inheret this permission, or is that not possible with location services architecture?

If it's not possible to aggregate permission to access location services, is there a way to persist permission for each of the discrete providers? Eg, the user shouldn't have to approve access for each map every single time they run the app... resulting in three alert views (the app and the two webviews), all asking the same thing every time it launches.

Is the only way to avoid this behavior to implement native API calls to the map providers rather than webviews?

Any input welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Use your appDelegate class for this.  If the location interaction code is simple, just create a method in appDelegate to get the authorization status and call it from the didFinishLaunching method.

I do something like this with a method like:

```
    - (BOOL)setupLocationMgr  
   {
        CLLocationManager *locationMgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationMgr.purpose = @"Location tracking for XXX app.";
        return [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized;
    }
```

The appDelegate then keeps the CLLocationManager object and can return it to any view that needs it.

Comment: how to return that to the view ?

Answer (score 1):

The way embedded web views handle the user location permission is based on the website. Each website that needs the user's location needs to specifically ask the user (Otherwise you could do some devious things...).

I think that you're seeing the alert each time the app is open because you're recreating another web view for display, and the cache might be cleared when the app is killed (not sure on this).

Comment: the cache ? Can you be more specific ?

Comment: By that I mean how long the webview will remember the answer to the location permission question. It might ask the user each time the webpage queries the user's location, or it might remember your answer for the lifetime of the webview. I'm not entirely sure how it works.